# Applying function to data.frame generates NAs while applying it to columns works

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, numeric, factors

I would like to apply a weight to a data frame in R that consists of variables that are numeric as well as factors. When I create a function that transforms factors into numerics and then weights the variable and apply this to any given column, it works well. However, when I apply it to the data.frame using the `apply` function, it generates NAs. For example:

```
set.seed(123)
frame <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100,10), y = c(rep("1",5), rep("2",5)))

weights <- 10
weight.fun <- function(x){
    x <- if(class(x) == "numeric" | class(x) == "integer"){x} else {as.numeric(levels(x))[x]}
    x*weights
}

weight.fun(frame$x)
# [1] 290 790 410 860 910  50 500 830 510 420
weight.fun(frame$y)
# [1] 10 10 10 10 10 20 20 20 20 20
apply(frame,2,weight.fun)
#        x  y
#  [1,] NA NA
#  [2,] NA NA
#  [3,] NA NA
#  [4,] NA NA
#  [5,] NA NA
#  [6,] NA NA
#  [7,] NA NA
#  [8,] NA NA
#  [9,] NA NA
# [10,] NA NA
```

Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: You should have a look at the `is.*` functions like `is.numeric()` and `is.character()`, etc. They can take the place of the awkward `class(x) == "whatever"`. You will also find that integers are also numeric, so `if(is.numeric(x)) x else ...` would suffice there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operation will work as intended if you use `sapply` instead instead of `apply`:

```
sapply(frame, weight.fun)
#         x  y
#  [1,] 290 10
#  [2,] 790 10
#  [3,] 410 10
#  [4,] 860 10
#  [5,] 910 10
#  [6,]  50 20
#  [7,] 500 20
#  [8,] 830 20
#  [9,] 510 20
# [10,] 420 20
```

The reason for this discrepancy is that `apply` operates on matrices (or arrays). From `?apply`:

> Returns a vector or array or list of values obtained by applying a
>   function to margins of an array or matrix.

Therefore your data frame `frame` will be converted to a matrix when using `apply`, meaning the data types for all columns will be forced to be the same (strings in your case):

```
as.matrix(frame)
#        x    y  
#  [1,] "29" "1"
#  [2,] "79" "1"
#  [3,] "41" "1"
#  [4,] "86" "1"
#  [5,] "91" "1"
#  [6,] " 5" "2"
#  [7,] "50" "2"
#  [8,] "83" "2"
#  [9,] "51" "2"
# [10,] "42" "2"
```

This explains the unexpected behavior with `apply` -- `weight.fun` is getting passed character vectors.

Meanwhile, `sapply` operates over lists, which is just what you want because data frames are lists. Using `sapply`, the type of each column is preserved from the data frame, so `weight.fun` is first called with an integer vector and then it is called with a factor.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issues is in your function. Your if statement was returning NA's so, this was not an apply issue and if x is a character it will fail. Writing the function like this seems to work with apply.

```
set.seed(123)
frame <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100,10), y = c(rep("1",5), rep("2",5)))

weight.fun <- function(x, w = 10){ 
  if(!class(x) == "numeric" & !class(x) == "integer") {
    if(class(x) == "factor") { x <- as.numeric(as.character(x)) }
    else if(class(x) == "character") { x <- as.numeric(x) }  
  } 
  return(x * w)
}

apply(frame, MARGIN = 2, FUN = weight.fun)
```